# Plot logarithmic axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm, yticks

I want to plot a graph with one logarithmic axis using matplotlib.

Sample program:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = [pow(10, i) for i in range(10)]  # exponential
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)

line, = ax.plot(a, color='blue', lw=2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 671):

You can use the [`Axes.set_yscale`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale) method. That allows you to change the scale after the `Axes` object is created. That would also allow you to build a control to let the user pick the scale if you needed to.

The relevant line to add is:

```
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

You can use `'linear'` to switch back to a linear scale. Here's what your code would look like:

```
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = [pow(10, i) for i in range(10)]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)

line, = ax.plot(a, color='blue', lw=2)

ax.set_yscale('log')

pylab.show()
```

[image: result chart]

Comment: This method is nice since it works with all sorts of plots (e.g. histograms), not just with "plot" (which is what semilogx/semilogy does)

Comment: I came here looking for how to use an axis for powers of two: pylab.gca().set_xscale('log',basex=2)

Comment: Matplotlib has `semilogy()`. Furthermore, it is easier to directly use `pyplot.yscale()` than to use `ax.set_yscale('log')`, as there is no need to get the `ax` object (which is not always immediately available).

Comment: If you want log scales on both axes, try `loglog()` or on x-axis only try `semilogx()`

Comment: @EOL I would advise the opposite.  It is better to use an explicit `ax` object that to use `pyplot` which only _might_ apply to the Axes you want it to.

Comment: @tcaswell While I do appreciate the fact that the object-oriented approach to plotting is more explicit, I must say that in many many years of usage of Matplotlib I have _never_ been bitten by the state machine approach that I was recommending for its ease of use… I sometimes do use the object-oriented approach, but only in some rare, more complicated plotting tasks.

Comment: Does set_yscale('log') uses base 10 as the default? I am not able to find any official documentation on the same.

Comment: @EricOLebigot For me it's the opposite, I use the object-oriented approach every day because my Qt-based programs have embedded Matplotlib graphs, and the `plt.do_something()` examples found everywhere on StackOverflow or in the documentation never work for me.

Comment: @outlier229 yes, the default is base 10. source: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.LogScale

Answer (score 400):

First of all, it's not very tidy to mix `pylab` and `pyplot` code. What's more, [pyplot style is preferred over using pylab](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related).

Here is a slightly cleaned up code, using only `pyplot` functions:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

a = [ pow(10,i) for i in range(10) ]

pyplot.subplot(2,1,1)
pyplot.plot(a, color='blue', lw=2)
pyplot.yscale('log')
pyplot.show()
```

The relevant function is [`pyplot.yscale()`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.yscale). If you use the object-oriented version, replace it by the method [`Axes.set_yscale()`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yscale). Remember that you can also change the scale of X axis, using [`pyplot.xscale()`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xscale) (or [`Axes.set_xscale()`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale)).

Check my question [What is the difference between ‘log’ and ‘symlog’?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305865/what-is-the-difference-between-log-and-symlog) to see a few examples of the graph scales that matplotlib offers.

Comment: `pyplot.semilogy()` is more direct.

Answer (score 111):

if you want to change the base of logarithm, just add:

```
plt.yscale('log',base=2)
```

Before Matplotlib 3.3, you would have to use basex/basey as the bases of log

Answer (score 78):

You simply need to use [semilogy](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.semilogy) instead of plot:

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot  as pyplot
a = [ pow(10,i) for i in range(10) ]
fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)

line, = ax.semilogy(a, color='blue', lw=2)
show()
```

Comment: There is also [semilogx](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.semilogx). If you need log on both axes, use [loglog](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.loglog)

Answer (score 13):

I know this is slightly off-topic, since some comments mentioned the `ax.set_yscale('log')` to be "nicest" solution I thought a rebuttal could be due. I would not recommend using `ax.set_yscale('log')` for histograms and bar plots. In my version (0.99.1.1) i run into some rendering problems - not sure how general this issue is. However both bar and hist has optional arguments to set the y-scale to log, which work fine.

references:
http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist

Answer (score 11):

So if you are simply using the unsophisticated API, like I often am (I use it in ipython a lot), then this is simply

```
yscale('log')
plot(...)
```

Hope this helps someone looking for a simple answer! :).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods given on this page ([semilogx](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/eb02b108ea181930ab37717c75e07ba792e01f1d/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L1908), [semilogy](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/eb02b108ea181930ab37717c75e07ba792e01f1d/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L1955), [loglog](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/eb02b108ea181930ab37717c75e07ba792e01f1d/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L1854-L1863)) but they all do the same thing under the hood, which is to call `set_xscale('log')` (for x-axis) and `set_yscale('log')` (for y-axis). Moreover, `plt.yscale`/`plt.scale` are functions in the state-machine, which make calls to `set_yscale`/`set_xscale` on the current Axes objects. Even for bar-charts (and histograms too since [they are just bar-charts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77382241/19123103)), the [`log=True`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/eb02b108ea181930ab37717c75e07ba792e01f1d/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L2431-L2432) parameter makes calls to `set_yscale('log')`/`set_xscale('log')` depending on the bar orientation.

So it doesn't matter which one you use, they all end up calling the same method anyway. By the way, on top of being able to choose the base of the log, you can also set minor tick locations in the same function call (using `subs` kwarg).

```py
data = np.random.choice(np.logspace(-0.5, 1, base=20), 10)
plt.plot(data)
plt.yscale('log', base=10, subs=[10**x for x in (0.25, 0.5, 0.75)], nonpositive='mask')
#                          ^^^ <-- 3 equal-spaced minor ticks       ^^^^ mask invalid values
```

[image: result]