# Matplotlib/Pylab - part of plot disappears after setting log scale

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, plot

I have a small code producing the following picture with this code:

Code 1:

```
hist, rhist = np.histogram(r, bins=40, range=(0, 0.25))
hist = -hist/np.trapz(rhist[:-1],hist)
plt.plot(rhist[:-1], hist)
```

Output of code 1:
[image]

Then I try setting the plot to have a logarithmic Y axis so that I can recognise small peaks more clearly. This is the result.

Code 2:

```
hist, rhist = np.histogram(r, bins=40, range=(0, 0.25))
hist = -hist/np.trapz(rhist[:-1],hist)
plt.semilogy(rhist[:-1], hist)
```

Output of code 2:
[image]

As you can see, part of my plot disappears. There are 40 bins, I can however only count about 15 in the new plot. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am using Enthought Canopy of the latest version for academic use. E.

UPDATE: I did find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027778/matplotlib-data-disappears-when-i-switch-to-a-semilog-plot), old, dead and unanswered though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's just not plotting those values because they are zero.

Log(0) = -Infinity.

Plotting that is going to make your graph look pretty rubbish...

Comment: Thank you. I did not even think about that and it is so obvious! :)

Answer (score 1):

Issue `plt.yscale('symlog')` at the end of your plotting.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305865/what-is-the-difference-between-log-and-symlog) for a description of `'symlog'`.

Answer (score 0):

A common **visual trick** to "display" zero in log scale is to use a very small value instead:

```
plt.semilogy(rhist[:-1], hist+1e-6)
```

In this case beaware of correct interpretation of plot though.

Comment: Good idea as well. I'd upvote you but I don't have the rep, haha.

Comment: If you're going to do this, then this really isn't how you should do it... You should use the `nonposy` argument. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3513150/432913) for more info.