# Scale a matplotlib plot so that small/large positive/negative differences can be shown

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

[image]

This plot is supposed to show differences in time, which can be both negative and positive values. Some differences are very small, while others are very large.

Can I scale the x-axis so that the resolution is very fine near x = 0 and coarse farther away from x = 0? Is it possible to have a logarithmic scale going outward from x = 0?

EDIT:

As suggested by @Evert, this solves the problem for me:

```
ax = gca()
...
ax.set_xscale("symlog")
```

and produces this plot:

[image]

Comment: None of those values are negative :P

Comment: @askewchan Good, soon you'll earn your "Smartass" silver badge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `symlog` setting in `xscale()`: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xscale

It scales logarithmically (also on the negative side), apart from a limited section around zero (which can be set using further keywords, see the documentation): that section is scaled linearly, thus avoiding all `log(0)` problems.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681975/matplotlibs-symlog-option-how-to-prevent-curves-that-come-back) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

I would make two subplots: plot the positive times in the right-hand subplot, and plot abs(negative times) in the left-hand subplot, with a [reversed x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051744/pyplot-reverse-y-axis).

> Is it possible to have a logarithmic scale going outward from x = 0?

No, because a logarithmic plot doesn't show zero --- as you approach the "left end" of the log-x axis, you go to negative infinity in log space, so you can't cross zero to get to the truly negative values.  You have to cut zero out somehow.