# Matplotlib logarithmic scale with zero value

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm

I have a very large and sparse dataset of spam twitter accounts and it requires me to scale the x axis in order to be able to visualize the distribution (histogram, kde etc) and cdf of the various variables (tweets_count, number of followers/following etc).

```
    > describe(spammers_class1$tweets_count)
  var       n   mean      sd median trimmed mad min    max  range  skew kurtosis   se
1   1 1076817 443.47 3729.05     35   57.29  43   0 669873 669873 53.23  5974.73 3.59
```

In this dataset, the value 0 has a huge importance (actually 0 should have the highest density). However, with a logarithmic scale these values are ignored. I thought of changing the value to 0.1 for example, but it will not make sense that there are spam accounts that have 10^-1 followers.

So, what would be a workaround in python and matplotlib ?

Comment: it would be nice if you put your axes/plot code so as to be corrected.

Comment: use `symlog` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305865/what-is-the-difference-between-log-and-symlog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 1 to each `x` value, *then* take the log:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [0, 10, 100, 1000]
y = [100, 20, 10, 50]
x = np.asarray(x) + 1 
y = np.asarray(y)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{0:g}'.format(x-1)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(x))
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Use

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{0:g}'.format(x-1)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(x))
```

to relabel the tick marks according to the non-log values of `x`.

(My original suggestion was to use `plt.xticks(x, x-1)`, but this would affect all axes. To isolate the changes to one particular axes, I changed all commands calls to `ax`, rather than calls to `plt`.)

---

`matplotlib` removes points which contain a `NaN`, `inf` or `-inf` value. Since `log(0)` is `-inf`, the point corresponding to `x=0` would be removed from a log plot.

If you increase all the x-values by 1, since `log(1) = 0`, the point corresponding to `x=0` will not be plotted at `x=log(1)=0` on the log plot.

The remaining x-values will also be shifted by one, but it will not matter to the eye since `log(x+1)` is very close to `log(x)` for large values of `x`.

Comment: yes, but I will not be able to say in my paper that 50% of spammers have 0 followers. because it will be shown as 10^0 and this will mean that they  have one follower (which is different).

Comment: You could relabel the tick marks with `plt.xticks`. I've edited the post to show how.

Comment: In order not to shift all of the data. How can I efficiently add 0.1 to 0 values, so they will come up at the 10^-1 and then relabel the ticks ? I know this is another question. but It might be a better way of doing it without contaminating all of the data -shifting only 0 values- (and looping over large numpy arrays is very slow)

Comment: If you have an array with many 0 values, you can change them to 0.1 with `x[x<=0] = 0.1`. Note that if the array is of dtype `int`, then you must first convert the array to dtype `float`: `x = x.astype('float')`.

Comment: I protest in the strongest terms to modifying data before plotting it.

Comment: @tcaswell: Please reread my answer. Exactly what are you objecting against?

Comment: @tcaswell. I'm very confused that you can object to modifying data, and yet recommend using `symlog`. `symlog` is plotting part of the data on a linear scale, and part on a logarithmic scale. If that isn't a modification of data before plotting, what is?

Comment: Using creative scales bothers me less than modifying the data, it is much harder to hide.  I am also reacting to your comments explaining how to add 0.1 to _just_ the zero entries.

Comment: Ordinarily, I would agree with you that *selectively* modifying data is a terrible idea. With continuous data, mapping 0 to 0.1 would be disasterous if there is already data at 0.1. However, if you read his question carefully he is dealing with integer-valued data. So mapping 0 to 0.1 and then plotting it at on a log scale simply maps the data at 0 to -1, to be adjacent to the data that was at 1, which is mapped to 0. In this context -- for integer data -- I don't think this solution is terrible.

Comment: In fact, it is **equivalent** to the symlog solution you suggest -- it produces a graph with two scales. Personally, I believe `log(x+1)` is a cognitively simpler answer since `log(x+1)` is smooth, and does not require one to adjust for two scales on one axis. `symlog` also does not highlight where the change of scale occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
ax1.set_xlim(0, 1e3)
```

Here is the [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/aspect_loglog.html) from matplotlib documentation.

And there it sets the limit values of the axes this way:

```
ax1.set_xlim(1e1, 1e3)
ax1.set_ylim(1e2, 1e3)
```

Comment: This doesn't show how to go with zero values on the logarithmic scale. as log(0) is undefined so matplotlib will ignore these values.Setting the xlim to 1e1 will make the x axis start from 0.1 and still would ignore 0 (I believe). I'll try it out anyway

Comment: at least as of july 2015, matplotlib is not ignoring zeros, it draws a straight line on the log plot all the way to the edge of the plot, which looks terrible and doesn't match matlab. hayer's comment doesn't seem true to me.