# How to exclude x=0 or y=0 values from scatter plot?

Tags: python, plot, scatter-plot, scatter

I have a scatter graph that looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to make it so that if x=0 or y=0 then that scatter point is ignored, and only the values where x and y are both greater than or equal to zero are taken:

[image]

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
x = df['tp']
y = df['tp1']

x = x[x > 0.0]
y = y[y > 0.0]


plt.scatter(x,y)
```

To which I get met with the following:

```
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

Is there a reason for why this isn't working, or a different solution that I could use?

Comment: The reason why it isn't working is that x and y are corresponding values, when you filter them separately you break the pairing. You need to zip them together, filter on both conditions and then unzip them back into x and y coords.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the context of the filter while filtering, but you can do:

```
x_filtered = x[ (x > 0.0) and (y> 0.0)]
y_filtered  = y[ (x > 0.0) and (y> 0.0)]

plt.scatter(x_filtered ,y_filtered)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you need to exclude both `x`s and `y`s where either one is `0`.

Imagine you have 10, `0`s in `x` and 5 in `y`. Your `x` and `y` size would not be the same. And more importantly you'll have wrong pairs of `x` and `y`s.

What you need?

find `x` and `y` rejection masks then apply them to both `x` an `y`s:

```
x = df['tp']
y = df['tp1']

xy_mask = x > 0.0 and y > 0.0

x = x[xy_mask]
y = y[xy_mask]

plt.scatter(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar answer is already given in this link. I hope it will help you out.

[Not plotting 'zero' in matplotlib or change zero to None [Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697417/not-plotting-zero-in-matplotlib-or-change-zero-to-none-python)