# Logscale plots with zero values in matplotlib *with negative exponents*

Tags: python, matplotlib

This question is highly related to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904755/logscale-plots-with-zero-values-in-matplotlib).

I'm trying to plot a graph in which the x-axis is

`[0] + [2**(x-4) for x in xrange(8)]`

The answer to the other question allows matplotlib to have an axis with `[0, 2**(0), 2**(1), 2**(2), 2**(3)]`, but it does not add the negative powers.

Basically, I want a log-scale plot with another point (placed at where `2**(-5)` would be horizontal if it existed instead) for `x=0`.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Here you do not take a power, you perform a bitwise *xor*. The power operator is `**` in Python.

Comment: The reason it does not allow this, is because at a log scale, you can not represent *negative* numbers, and `2^(-2)` is `-4`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem 2^(-2) (mathematically) is 0.25. I didn't write it this way in the code.

Comment: Well then it might make sense to share what exactly you did.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - is it clearer now?

Comment: I suppose the problem is the `0` in your list. If you use `[2**(x-5) for x in xrange(9)]` instead, does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot it with matplotlib's `loglog`. Here is a basic example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0] + [2**(x-4) for x in range(8)])
f = lambda x: 10**x

plt.loglog(x, f(x), basex=2, basey=10)
```

As you can see, you can pass the x and y base seperately and it also gives `2**(-1)...`

Here is a picture of the example:

[image: plot]

I don't know if I understand the second part of your question.

**EDIT** I think i might understand now. Since it is not possible to have a 0 on a log scale, here is a symbolic approach:

On your scale, the smallest number on the x-axis was `2**(-4)` so I use `2**(-5)` as a symbolic zero an rename the ticks accordingly. This is done via `xticks`:

```
plt.xticks([2**i for i in range(-5,4)], [r"0"] + [r"$2^{%d}$" %(int(i)) for i in range(-4,4)])
```

The first argument `[2**i for i in range(-5,4)]` creates the positions of the ticks and the second argument the labels.

It now looks like this:

[image: plot2]

Remember: A "zero" here is actually a `2**(-5)`!

Comment: This is nice, but it doesn't have a tick for 0 in the x axis. I want to have a tick for 0, and ticks for 2^(-4),...

Comment: And on the 0 tick you want to plot data, that is negative or zero? I mean a log scale for negative or zero numbers doesn't really make sense. There simply is no 0 on a log scale, because the log diverges at 0

Comment: There are no negative values. x values are just 0 and powers of 2 and the y values are all positive (as in the figure I had in the question).

Comment: I hope this fits your needs now