# Logarithmic scale in x axis but only up to a certain value, in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scale

I'd like to do a graph like the one below
[image]

The figure can be found in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06209)

Here the x-axis scale is logaritmic up to `l=30` and linear for `l>30`. How can I achieve something like that in python using matplotlib?

Comment: This looks like 4 subplots very close together, where the joint y-axis is removed with a lot of fiddling to get ticks, tick labels and limits exactly fit.  Some [broken axis implementations](https://github.com/bendichter/brokenaxes) can be used as inspiration for the fiddling needed.

Comment: With [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41126461/12046409) comes a complete implementation of a combined logarithmic and linear x-axis. This answers the question in the title. The two lower subplots can be created similarly.

Comment: @JohanC It does, thank you. Sorry I didn't find it before typing my answer, thanks again.