# Is there any way to put two different scale types on the same axis? (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I’d like to divide my x-axis on two different parts - the first part with linear scale and another with log scale. Is it possible and if so, how?

Let’s say that I have:

```
x = [100, 50, 30, 10, 1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.01]
y = [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

I’d like to have the x-axis from 100 to 10 as a linear scale, and another part from 10 to 0.01 as a log scale.

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746491/combining-a-log-and-linear-scale-in-matplotlib

Comment: Does this answer your question? [combining a log and linear scale in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746491/combining-a-log-and-linear-scale-in-matplotlib)

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you all for your answers and apologies for not answering you for so long time. I don't know why, but my answer from December was not added. I've just realized that, so here it is again: thanks a lot!