# how to show an interval in logarithmic scale and other linear in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib and I want to plot a graph in which the negative part of y axis has large numbers while the positive part has smaller values and the positive part is more valuable to show. So I prefer to draw the negative part of y axis in logarithmic scale and positive part in linear(normal) scale. Here I show whole the plot with log scale and this is my code:

```
    plt.plot(time_stamps,objs,'-rD', markevery=markers_on )
    markers_on=  list(i for i in range(len(upper_bound)))
    plt.plot(time_stamps,upper_bound,'-bD', markevery=markers_on )
    markers_on=  list(i for i in range(len(best_P_list)))
    plt.plot(exce_time_list,best_P_list,'-gD', markevery=markers_on)
    plt.xlabel("x", fontsize=10)
    plt.ylabel("y ", fontsize=10)
    plt.yscale('symlog')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I show positive part of y axis in linear scale?

Comment: You can always use funcscale https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.FuncScale but if you want alternating labels you’ll have to either hard code them or make a custom formatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely reworked my answer because I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746491/combining-a-log-and-linear-scale-in-matplotlib) which explains how to divide axes to behave differently.

Now, we still need to separate the different values and steps but it's much clearer.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np


vals = np.array([-1e10, -1e7, 1e3, 1e2, -1e8, -1e1, 1e3, 500])
steps = np.array([0, 5, 1, 4, 9, 20, 7, 15])


def plot_diff_scales(vals, steps):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(steps[vals >= 0], vals[vals >= 0], "-gD")  # only positive values
    ax.set_yscale("linear")
    ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)  # hide bottom of box
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)  # hide x-axis entirely
    ax.set_ylabel("Linear axis")
    # Dividing the axes
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    ax_log = divider.append_axes("bottom", size=2, pad=0, sharex=ax)
    # Acting on the log axis
    ax_log.set_yscale("symlog")
    ax_log.spines["top"].set_visible(False)  # hide top of box
    ax_log.plot(steps[vals < 0], vals[vals < 0], "-bD")  # only negative values
    ax_log.set_xlabel("X axis")
    ax_log.set_ylabel("Symlog axis")
    # Show delimiter
    ax.axhline(y=0, color="black", linestyle="dashed", linewidth=1)
    # Plotting proper
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


plot_diff_scales(vals, steps)
```

[image]