# Equidistant ticks on colorbar using SymLogNorm in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scale, colorbar

I would like to enforce that the ticks of my colorbar are equally spaced on the colorbar (not in their values) using `SymLogNorm()`, like they are for example in the default mode of `LogNorm()`. How could I do this without doing it by hand, i.e. without doing like the following:

`plt.colorbar(ticks=[vmin, value1, ... , vmax])`

What I want is basically to have the same ticks as I would have using `LogNorm()` (Magnitudes). Here is how my code basically works:

```
import ...
...
y    = np.loadtxt('my_data.dat')
vmin_a = y[0]
vmax_a = y[1]

norm_a = SymLogNorm(linthresh=0.5, linscale=0.03, vmin=vmin_a, vmax=vmax_a)

plt.figure(1)
plt.scatter(x[0], x[1], marker='.', s=7, linewidths=0, c=x[3], cmap= \
          plt.get_cmap('RdBu_r'), norm=norm_rs)
plt.xlabel(xax)    
plt.ylabel(yax)    
plt.colorbar()

pl.xlim([vmin_a, vmax_a])
pl.ylim([vmin_a, vmax_a])

plt.show()
```

I think the following picture explains very well how I do not want it, i.e. how it actually looks like:
[image]
I am thankful for any hint.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, one has to set ticks by hand using SymLogNorm. I solved my problem by defining:

```
tick_locations_plot=( [vmin]
                  + [-(10.0**x) for x in range(minlog-1,-logthresh-1,-1)]
                  + [0.0]
                  + [(10.0**x) for x in range(-logthresh,maxlog-1)]
                  + [vmax] )
```

where

```
maxlog=int(np.ceil( np.log10(vmax) ))
minlog=int(np.ceil( np.log10(-vmin) ))
```

Then using

```
plt.colorbar(ticks=tick_locations)
```

does what I was looking for.

Comment: What is `logthresh`?

Comment: @gauteh it's a threshold in to determine where the plot is log verse linear. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305865/what-is-the-difference-between-log-and-symlog)