# how to reformat the x-axis on a chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a following simple graph in matplotlib:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.uniform(-3, 2, 100)
data = np.append(data, [-5, -10, -50, -55])


plt.scatter(range(104), data, marker='o', color='b', label='Data Points')

plt.savefig("example.png")
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

You can see that the values -50 and -55 distort the whole graph. I want to change the linearity of the Y axis to get this:

[image]

In other words Y asis should have values 0, -10, -30, -50, -100 that is nonlinear. How can I do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired formatting on the Y-axis, you can set the y-scale to [symlog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305865/what-is-the-difference-between-log-and-symlog) and then set custom tick labels:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.uniform(-3, 2, 100)
data = np.append(data, [-5, -10, -50, -55])

plt.scatter(range(104), data, marker='o', color='b', label='Data Points')
plt.yscale('symlog')

# Set custom y-tick labels
plt.yticks([0, -10, -30, -50, -100], ['0', '-10', '-30', '-50', '-100'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Sorry, no. This will keep the spaces between ticks and labels the same. What I want is to make it nonlinear (check my hand written example)

Comment: @vojtam is it better now? take into account, that symlog is an example and you can choose other forms of non-linearity.