# Matplotlib: Avoid congestion in X axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cumulative-frequency

I'm using this code to plot a cumulative frequency plot:

```
lot = ocum.plot(x='index', y='cdf', yticks=np.arange(0.0, 1.05, 0.1))

plot.set_xlabel("Data usage")`
plot.set_ylabel("CDF")

fig = plot.get_figure()
fig.savefig("overall.png")
```

How it appears as follows and is very crowded around the initial part. This is due to my data spread. How can I make it more clear? (uploading to postimg because I don't have enough reputation points)

http://postimg.org/image/ii5z4czld/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I understood what you want: give more space to the visualization of the "CDF" development for smaller "data usage" values, right? Typically, you would achieve this by changing your X axis scale from linear to logarithmic. Head over to [Plot logarithmic axes with matplotlib in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773814/plot-logarithmic-axes-with-matplotlib-in-python) for seeing different ways to achieve that. The simplest might be, in your case, to replace `plot()` with `semilogx()`.