# Using a logarithmic scale in matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have the following plot in which the X range is very wide and the shape of the graph near 1 MeV to 0.1 MeV is suppressed.

I want a plot where the X scale has equal separation (or equal grid) between 10,1,0.1 MeV.
[image]

Comment: where is your current code snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot logarithmic axes with matplotlib in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773814/plot-logarithmic-axes-with-matplotlib-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `matplotlib`'s [`semilogx`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.semilogx) function instead of `plot` to make the `x` axis logarithmic.

Here's a short example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.01,14,0.01)
y = np.log(100*x)

fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

ax1.plot(x,y)
ax1.set_xlim(x[-1],x[0])
ax1.set_title('plot')

ax2.semilogx(x,y)
ax2.set_xlim(x[-1],x[0])
ax2.set_title('semilogx')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

also consider 
    `ax.set_xscale("log")`
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/aspect_loglog.html