# how to show the vertical in logarithmic in matplotlib of python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, logarithm

how to show the vertical in logarithmic in ***matplotlib*** in python.

For instance, y is 1,10,100,1000 instead of 1,2,3,....

I need this because I want to show some comparison  which one of them is too big for instance one of them reaches 200 in maximum point while the two others reach to maximum 3.5. I need to show clearly difference of two low, also I should show the third in the same figure!

Comment: you could also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773814/plot-logarithmic-axes-with-matplotlib-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `ax`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
y=[2,14,56,170,600,1100]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

or if you use `plt`:

```
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image]