# How to set my x-axis value according to my values in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How to set equal bandwidth between xticks in matplotlib.

I am plotting  graph and for x value ticks and i want my bin to be exact as related to my values.

my xticks are = `[0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100]`

```
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

plt.plot(tuned_parameter,accuracy_list)

plt.xlabel("Hyperparameter")

plt.ylabel("accuracy")

plt.xticks(tuned_parameter) 

plt.title("Plot for accuracy with different hyperparameter")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the "tick frequency" on x or y axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

Comment: If I understood this question correctly, you want to have equal spacing between the mentioned ticks, which are not equally spaced. I think what you are looking for is a log scale on the x-axis, which you find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773814/plot-logarithmic-axes-with-matplotlib-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to set the ticks as the ones you mention, why don't you simply use:

```
plt.xticks([0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100])
```

Remember, the plt.xticks() takes as an argument a list. An empty list will remove the ticks altogether.

If you have the plt.xlim() up to 10 for example, this command will increase your limit to include the ticks.

And since I sense a semilog plot, why don't you use plt.semilogx(...) instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use your defined variable inside `plt.xticks(my_variable)`. As it takes list as an argument. More details about ticks can be found here,

> https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Comment: but they are not coming in equal range of bins as my values are [0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100] , os its plotting 0.001 at extreme left and 100 at extreme right ..

Comment: @VishalSuryavanshi: To get more help, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @VishalSuryavanshi please edit your post with an example that we can run and see the outcome. Because generally using above method we can plot what you are expecting.