# Creating a histogram using np.logspace() with a KDE superimposed

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have a large dataset(50k rows) and I wanted to create a histogram from the data with density along the Y axis and values log scaled on the x axis, with a KDE plot superimposed.

This is very small subset of the data being used:

```
A       B    C
1       1   4200
1       4   94000
1       4   81000
1       3   30000
1       3   29000
1       1   20400


Current code:
columns= ['A','B','C']
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=columns)

data=df[['C']].dropna().values
data=np.logspace(data)
plt.hist(data, bins='auto')
```

I currently get the following error
logspace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'stop'
When I don't use logspace I am able to get a histogram, but not the one I am looking for.  I am very new to python so the help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.logspace` works like `np.linspace` and is used to create an array that is evenly spaced just in log space. `np.logspace` takes a start value and an end value to create an array and you can check the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html). It does not take the log of your data. You will want to use `np.log` for that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation let me rephrase what I am asking.  We have a hint to use log-spaced bins on the X-axis so we should use np.logspace for this. I am new to statistics and need help in how I would choose the start and end for this function as I am also unfamiliar on how to choose the number of bins.

Comment: You want to create your bins using `np.logspace` then for your histogram. Something like `bins = np.logspace(np.min(data),np.max(data))` then `plt.hist(data,bins=bins)`

Comment: I am getting the following errors: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power return _nx.power(base, y), RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract  a = op(a[slice1], a[slice2]), RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply  boffset = -0.5 * dr * totwidth * (1 - 1 / nx).  My data contains both negatives and 0 as possible values.

Comment: Then you have answered your own problem... You can't use log if you have negative numbers or zero so you need to use .01 for your `start` value which means your histogram won't count those numbers.

Comment: Thanks this helped me with the histogram portion. Now I am trying to add the KDE on top. I have the KDE seperate using kde=df.data.plot.kde(). I need the combine these 2 types of visualization now.

Comment: I have referenced this thread already and while it is helpful. I am having trouble changing the X-axis to a log scale when following along with that thread.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773814/plot-logarithmic-axes-with-matplotlib-in-python

Comment: If you are having additional problems please update your question and/or post a new question referencing your issue (assuming you can't find help in another SO post)