# How to plot graph with unproportional Y axis in python?

Tags: python

I want to plot bitcoin historical prices. Bitcoin was traded at a comparatively low prices back in times and it's hard to show the fluctuations on the graph when the price was small. I want to plot the graph like in the picture below (the link for the picture provided below) where I can stretch regions with small prices and squeeze regions with high prices.

I also included picture with what I could plot using historical prices of Bitcoin

[Bitcoin Historical Prices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ2lU.png)

[This is what I could reach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZkwE.png)

Comment: Coindesk graph Y axis is in log scale. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/773814/1589191) should help.

Comment: Have you tried setting the y-scale to `log`, https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html#matplotlib.pyplot.yscale, or perhaps usings a semi-log y-scale, https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.semilogy.html#matplotlib-pyplot-semilogy? Also, do you have a link to the data you're using?

Comment: @PhilippeDixon I got the data from here https://www.investing.com/crypto/bitcoin/historical-data

Comment: @EmilMGeorge ,thank you guys, I tried doing it in log scale and it Worked!

Comment: @PhilippeDixon ,thank you guys, I tried doing it in log scale and it Worked!