# Matplotlib - How I can define the x-axis with different intervals like the next picture? I would like to open certain intervals

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

[image]

I would like to create a similar graph, in this case China and USA have huge PIB that I cant see the details for small countries

Comment: It's called logarithmic scale.

Comment: [Duplicate Question] Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773814/plot-logarithmic-axes-with-matplotlib-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can use ax.set_xscale:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

plt.scatter(your_data)
ax = plt.gca() #get current axis object
ax.set_xscale('log') #you can use 'symlog' if your data is close to 0
ax.set_yscale('log')
#if you don't want to show the ticks in scientific notation
for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis]:
    formatter = ScalarFormatter()
    formatter.set_scientific(False)
    axis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```