# Need Help In Matlplotlib Plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am given a [dataset](https://pastebin.com/2aYxLBaA) and I am supposed to plot: How much does each player get paid per game on average?

I converted the dataset into a NumPy array:

```py
Salary = np.array([KobeBryant_Salary, JoeJohnson_Salary, LeBronJames_Salary, 
                   CarmeloAnthony_Salary, DwightHoward_Salary, ChrisBosh_Salary, 
                   ChrisPaul_Salary, KevinDurant_Salary, DerrickRose_Salary, 
                   DwayneWade_Salary])
Games = np.array([KobeBryant_G, JoeJohnson_G,LeBronJames_G, CarmeloAnthony_G, 
                  DwightHoward_G, ChrisBosh_G, ChrisPaul_G, KevinDurant_G, 
                  DerrickRose_G, DwayneWade_G])
```

After that, I wrote a for loop, and iterated through this array:

```py
for i in range(0,10):
    plt.plot(Salary[i]/Games[i])
```

Since one of the players had played 0 games it is showing the `ZeroDivisionError` in my plot.
I wanted to know is this the right approach? Also if it is correct can I please how can I format the y axis so that the lower values are visible better (I tried playing with `yticks` but it didn't help much).

[image]

Comment: div by zero may be acceptable. For scaling check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773814/plot-logarithmic-axes-with-matplotlib-in-python)

Comment: Sir is my approach correct? I have just started to learn python this week

Comment: What is `FieldGoals`? Your code is not reproducible.

Comment: I am sorry it is Games[i]

Comment: Approach seems ok. You may change 0 with nan, but that's esthetics. You may loop over the division or use some try except, but that would defy the use of numpy.array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code. It does not throw any `ZeroDivisionError`, rather throws a warning. For improving the visibility of the results, you should use `plt.yscale("log")` so that lower values will be visible.

Comment: Thanks A Lot, Scaling Is Much Better: https://imgur.com/a/deLM9I1 

. Is my approach fine, asking this because we are passing only one argument into plot() while we are supposed to pass 2 arguments.

Comment: Its a matter of what you want to show on the x-axis? If you want to show the number of games played then you need to put an array on the x-axis accordingly. I am sure that you want to show salary on the y-axis. Right now the plot is just showing `range(0,10)` on the x-axis.

Comment: Like nothing is specified as such, i am just trying to learn things.  As per my understanding right now the x axis is showing the iteration range while the y axis is showing salary/game. So in order to get like year on the x-axis we need to pass an array of years, salary/game ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I exactly said and that's what you exactly should do :).