# How to plot an histogram correctly with numpy, and match it with the density function?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, statistics, probability-density

TL;DR: **How to plot the result of `np.histogram(..., density=True)` correctly with Numpy?**

Using `density=True` should help to match the histogram of the sample, and the density function of the underlying random variable, but it doesn't:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = np.random.randn(10000)
h, bins = np.histogram(y, bins=1000, density=True)
plt.bar(bins[:-1], h)
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
f = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x)
plt.plot(x, f, color="green")
plt.show()
```

**Why aren't the histogram and probability density functions scaled accordingly?**

[image: plt.bar output]

In this case, an observation shows that a 1.6 scaling would be better:

```py
plt.plot(x, 1.6 * f, color="green")
```

Also, this works normally:

```py
plt.hist(y, bins=100, density=True)
```

[image: plt.hist output]

Why?

Comment: The figure isn't clear; I only see the histogram, and not the density function. About the histogram, it looks okay to me -- it is supposed to have total area = 1, and, eyeballing it as averaging about 0.2 over the range -2.5 to 2.5, that seems plausible. If you add up all the rectangles, exactly what do you get?

Comment: @RobertDodier I updated the screenshot, do you see the same behaviour if you run my sample code?

Comment: Okay, when I run your code, I see the same image as the first plot you showed, which is incorrect as you pointed out. However, I see that `h.sum()*0.0075762` yields 1.0000002056823407 where 0.0075762 is the bin interval, as found by inspecting `bins`. That suggests the histogram was constructed correctly and therefore the problem is in the plotting of it.

Comment: On looking at this again, it appears that `plt.bar(bins[:-1], h)` is plotting bars which are much wider than the histogram's bins -- the bins are something like 0.007 in width, but the bars displayed are much wider, maybe 0.5 or even larger. Does `plt.bar` have an idea about the minimum width it allows? I see in the second image, the bars are much narrower.

Comment: @RobertDodier Oh that's right, maybe should we use `plt.bar` differently in combination with `np.histogram`?

Comment: Maybe there's a way to tell `plt.bar` to forget about its minimum bar width or whatever is stopping it from accurately portraying the bins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

- The default bar width of `.bar()` is too big (`.hist()` adjusts width internally).
- The number of bars is too high for the default figsize (that's why 100 bins is OK but 1000 is not).

---

In `Axes.hist`, bar widths are computed by `np.diff(bins)` ([source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/39582424f8ce5e042e4e39eeac94893f222c9f8b/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L6877-L6896)). Since it allows a multi-dimensional array, there are a whole lot of validation and reshaping done behind the scenes but if we set all that aside, for a 1D array, `Axes.hist` is just a wrapper around `np.histogram` and `Axes.bar` whose (abridged) code looks like the following:

```py
height, bins = np.histogram(x, bins)
width = np.diff(bins)
boffset = 0.5 * width
Axes.bar(bins[:-1]+boffset, height, width)
```

On the other hand, `Axes.bar` iteratively adds `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` objects to an Axes using a default width of 0.8, ([source implementation](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/39582424f8ce5e042e4e39eeac94893f222c9f8b/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L2517-L2535)), so if a bar is particularly tall and subsequent bars are short, the short ones will be hidden behind the tall ones.

The following code (kind of) illustrates the points made above. The histograms are the same; for example the tallest bars are the same. Note that, in the figure below the figsize is 12"x5" and each Axes is roughly 3" wide), so given that the default dpi is 100, it can only show roughly 300 dots horizontally which means it cannot show all 1000 bars correctly. We need an appropriately wide figure to show all bars correctly.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

# sample
y = np.random.default_rng(0).standard_normal(10000)
N = 1000
h, bins = np.histogram(y, bins=N, density=True)
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
f = stats.norm.pdf(x)

# figure
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(12,5))
a0 = axs[0].bar(bins[:-1], h)
a1 = axs[1].bar(bins[:-1]+0.5*np.diff(bins), h, np.diff(bins))
h_hist, bins_hist, a2 = axs[2].hist(y, bins=N, density=True)
for a, t in zip(axs, ['Axes.bar with default width', 'Axes.bar with width\nrelative to bins', 'Axes.hist']):
    a.plot(x, f, color="green")
    a.set_title(t)

# label tallest bar of each Axes
axs[0].bar_label(a0, [f'{h.max():.2f}' if b.get_height() == h.max() else '' for b in a0], fontsize=7)
axs[1].bar_label(a1, [f'{h.max():.2f}' if b.get_height() == h.max() else '' for b in a1], fontsize=7)
axs[2].bar_label(a2, [f'{h_hist.max():.2f}' if b.get_height() == h_hist.max() else '' for b in a2], fontsize=7)

# the bin edges and heights from np.histogram and Axes.hist are the same
(h == h_hist).all() and (bins == bins_hist).all()     # True
```

[image: result1]

For example, if we plot the same figure with `figsize=(60,5)` (everything else the same), we get the following figure where the bars are correctly shown (in particular `Axes.hist` and `Axes.bar` with adjusted widths are the same).

[image: with figsize=(60,5)]

Comment: Wow, excellent answer, thanks! PS: is `Axes.hist` the same as when I did `plt.hist` in my question? (same code under the hood?)

Comment: @Basj yes, `plt.hist` calls `Axes.hist` under the hood. It's a function in the state-based interface where the Axes is created implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

how about using auto bins ?

```
h, bins = np.histogram(y, bins='auto', density=True)
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but why doesn't it work with `bins=1000` or `100`? (in this case the scaling is wrong, why?)

Comment: in this case, i think it depends on the data size, if you increase the input data size and use bins=1000 or bins=100 it works

Answer (score 0):

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = np.random.randn(10000)
h, bins = np.histogram(y, bins=100, density=True)
x = np.linspace(bins.min(), bins.max(), 100)
f = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x)
plt.bar(bins[:-1], h, width=bins[1] - bins[0])
plt.plot(x, f, color="green")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("Density")
plt.title("Histogram and Density Function")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @HarshChitaliya! For future reference, please post a screenshot of the result, it would be useful.